# Como enviar notificação para todos os usuários do OneSignal com Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, api

Olá!

Eu estou aprendendo notificações com `flutter` e `oneSignal`. Descobri como enviar notificações para usuários específicos, mas não sei como envia-las para vários usuários. Meu código até o momento é esse:

```
OneSignal.shared.postNotification(OSCreateNotification(
          playerIds: ['e2926936-48d7-46c7-a093-169c19b902ee'],
          content: 'Mensagem de teste',
          heading: 'Acho que esta funcionando'));
```

No `playerIds` é onde coloca os usuários para enviar. Ele espera uma lista, mas buscando na internet vi que para enviar para todos usuários é só deixar `playerIds` vazio. Tentei desta forma e não consegui. tentei essas maneiras: `playerIds: []; playerIds: null; playerIds: [''];`, tentei também excluir a linha, mas da excessão todas as tentativas

Enfim, preciso que envie notificação para todos os usuários de uma vez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na [documentação](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/flutter-sdk#postnotification) do método `postNotification` diz que:

> Please note that you must specify at least one OneSignal user ID that the notification should be sent to, using the playerIds property.

(Tradução livre: Favor notar que você precisa especificar pelo menos um ID de usuário que a notificação deve ser mandada, utilizando a propriedade `playerIds`)

Isto é, não existe essa possibilidade de deixar em branco ou nulo para enviar para todos. Aonde você leu isso?

O outro método `postNotificationWithJson`também espera uma lista de `PlayerIds`.

Para enviar uma notificação para todos os usuários, utilize o Dashboard do OneSignal, conforme as instruções [aqui](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/sending-notifications):

- Clique na aba `Messages`
- Escolha como audiência "Subscribed Users" (Que caso você não tenha alterado representa todos os dispositivos inscritos)
- Digite o título, subtítulo, mensagem, imagem e as demais configurações de sua notificação.
- Escolha demais configurações como agendamento, campos extra para **deep-linking** ou prioridade.
- Aperte o botão "Send"

Para uma melhor descrição das funcionalidades consulte a [documentação oficial](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/sending-notifications)

Comment: Ah sim, eu tinha lido também que precisa de um playerId, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HQ7sIhzQGNk, nesse vídeo ai o Thizer Aplicativo ensina como usar,  e em um dos comentários ele fala 'É pra funcionar deixando o playerIds vazio ;)' em resposta a pergunta: Como faz pra mandar notificação pra todos no flutter?

Comment: Eu consigo enviar as notificação pelo site do OneSignal, mas eu gostaria de enviar pelo aplicativo, em código sabe

Comment: Acredito q a unica maneira vai ser obtendo todos os playerID para enviar né?

Comment: Acredito que sim. Não vai resolver, mas uma dica que talvez ajude é você utilizar a função  ```setExternalUserId``` para associar uma chave mais significativa a cada usuário.

Comment: Me perdoe a demora, como nao trabalhei no projeto esses dias, acabei nem vindo aqui, então irei estudar essa externalUserId, acho q irá resolver meu problema, obrigado